# Best way to find the sum of elements in an array with less than O(n) time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

There is standard way of adding integers using loop like,

```
sum =0;
for(int i =0;i<arraySize;i++){
     sum+=array[i];
}
```

The above logic time complexity is O(n) but if n is very large (consider 10^10) then it will take more time to compute. So,please give me any solution that will work with less than O(n) time complexity.

Comment: Let's see: you want to sum each element in an array ... but you want something faster than looking at each element in the array, Hmmm...  Good luck!  Note: you *CAN* get "faster" (e.g. run separate threads in parallel, execute on a GPU, use pointer arithmetic instead of an index, etc.) ... but you *CANNOT* improve on the "algorithmic complexity" of O(n).

Comment: You can improve the computing time with multithreading.

Comment: Yeah, that's not possible.

Comment: All elements must be accessed unless there is special information such as all elements are the same (or Regular sequence).

Comment: if anyone want to downgrade this question, tell me, what is mistake & solution to the problem also

Comment: A) you are cross tagging B) it is not clear what you are asking for. It is not possible to visit N array slots with smaller than N steps. We can't change reality just because you don't like the way reality behaves.

Comment: the complexity could be less than `O(n) ` only if the elements in the array  follow same pattern (and not always in that case too). Otherwise you cannot be faster than `O(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

Consider looping through in blocks

```
sum =0;
for(int i =0;i<arraySize; i = i + 5){
     sum+=array[i];
     sum+=array[i+1];
     sum+=array[i+2];
     sum+=array[i+3];
     sum+=array[i+4];
}
```

Of course you need to correctly check for out of bounds.

*In this trivial* example I doubt there are any gains to be made

Comment: This does not change the complexity.

Comment: Not only that, but it attempts to read beyond bounds when `arraySize%5` is non-zero.

Comment: @TobySpeight My answer quite clearly states *you need to correctly check for out of bounds*

Answer (score -1):

You can do so by keeping a record of the sum of the array at all times. Start with an empty array and an empty variable `sum`. Then, whenever you add an item to the array, update the sum accordingly.

There are 2 major operations that affect the sum of an array of numbers: Adding a new number to the array, and removing a number from the array. When adding, the sum becomes the previous sum added to the new number. Thus simply add the value of the new number to the `sum` variable. When Removing an item, the sum becomes the sum less the number being removed. So subtract the value of the item being removed from the `sum`. More operations can be performed, but they are all based on these two.

Thus you can implement `insert`, `pop` and `replace`  methods or functions to abstract this work for you.

Therefore, whenever you add or delete an item, you go through some O(1) arithmetic to recompute the sum. But you can access the sum in O(1) time, as the sum is in a variable. This will of course require that you never directly change values of the array without using your functions / methods.

Unfortunately, I do not know C nor Java well enough to provide an implementation. I hope that my sketching out of the data structure helps for that.

EDIT: Here is a Python implementation to show the concept. Hopefully you can get the core out of it.

```python
class ArraySum:
    ''' contains an array of numbers and a representation of the
        sum, which is updated in each insert/pop/replace operation '''
    def __init__(self):
        self._data = []
        self.sum = 0

    def append(self, elem):
    ''' add an item to the array'''
        self.sum += elem # update sum
        self._data.append(elem) # add to array

    def pop(self, i=None):
    ''' remove the item at index i of the array'''
        if i is None:
            i = len(self._data)
        self.sum -= self._data[i]
        return self._data.pop(i)

    def replace(self, i, elem):
    ''' replace the item at i by a new element'''
        self.sum -= self._data[i]
        self.sum += elem
        self._data[i] = elem

if __name__ == '__main__':
    a = ArraySum()

    a.append(4)
    print(a.sum) # sum = 0 + 4 
    a.append(8)
    print(a.sum) # sum = sum + 8 
    a.pop(1)
    print(a.sum) # sum = sum - 8 
    a.replace(0, 1) 
    print(a.sum) # sum = sum - 4 + 1
```